# Необходимо, чтобы в body post запроса в Postman генерировалось случайное значение

Tags: postman

Необходимо, чтобы в body post запроса в Postman генерировалось случайное значение в одной из строк.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо в нужном значении открыть {{ и начать вводить random... Postman сам предложит варианты (рандомное имя, число и т.д).
Конкретно в данном случае json выглядит так:

```
`{"name": "{{$randomFullName}}"}`
```